# How to export database connection string node / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, export

I am trying to turn the following database connection string into a module:

```
require('dotenv').load();
var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_USER_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME
    },
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 7
    }
});
```

So far I tried:

```
require('dotenv').load();
module.exports = {
knex : require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_USER_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME
    },
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 7
    }
})

}
```

In my app.js file:

```
var knex = require('./models/database');
knex.select().table('users').then(function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(value) {
        console.log(value.first_name);
    });
});
```

This returns the error 'knex' is undefined. I think the way my module is being exported is incorrect... can someone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're exporting an object containing `knex`.
Either add `knex` to the require:

```
var knex = require('./models/database').knex;
```

or change your export to

```
module.exports = require('knex')({ ... })
```